# Converting non-VBO to VBO (Android / Java specific)

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm having trouble understanding if my VBO code is correct.  Below is my code which is working, but non-VBO, then I've shown what I've done in my attempts to get VBO's working, I've had some success in that my Sprites/Quads are drawn, but when they are drawn, I'm not seeing any performance increase.  Could someone please advise if I'm doing this correctly, there are only one of two tuts out there specifically for VBO's on Android in Java (I've looked at C examples, but am not having any joy with them).

I'm not sure if I'm right in putting some of the code in my constructor - should this code no get called every time I draw a sprite?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Standard (Non VBO code, Note, X/YplotLeft/Right/Top/Bottom are correctly defined)**

```
//This code is the from the drawSprite method of my VBO Class.

    vertices[0]=xPlotLeft;
    vertices[1]=yPlotTop;
    vertices[2]=0;
    vertices[3]=0;
    vertices[4]=0;

    vertices[5]=xPlotRight;
    vertices[6]=yPlotTop;
    vertices[7]=0;
    vertices[8]=1;
    vertices[9]=0;

    vertices[10]=xPlotLeft;
    vertices[11]=yPlotBottom;
    vertices[12]=0;
    vertices[13]=0;
    vertices[14]=1;

    vertices[15]=xPlotRight;
    vertices[16]=yPlotBottom;
    vertices[17]=0;
    vertices[18]=1;
    vertices[19]=1;

    //Reset Byte Buffer position

    vertexBuf.rewind();
    vertexBuf.put(vertices).position(0);

    //Bind the texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);      
    //Use the program created earlier
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
    //Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix2, 0, mvpMatrix, 0,  mRotationMatrix, 0);
    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");
     // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix2, 0);
    //Set starting position for vertices
    vertexBuf.position(0);
    //Specify attributes for vertex (X,Y,Z)
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf);
    //Enable attribute for position
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);
    //Set starting position for vertices (texture)
    vertexBuf.position(3);
    //Specify attributes for vertex (S T for textures)
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, vertexBuf);
    //Enable attribute for texture
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoords);
    //Enable Alpha blending and set blending function
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND); 
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //Draw
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    //Disable Alpha blending
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

**VBO Code**

Defined at class level:

```
//Buffer object for VBO (We will copy data from floatBuffer into this)
    final int buffers[] = new int[1];
```

I've added the following code into the constructor of my VBO class:

```
    //Generate buffers as needed

GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);

// Bind to the buffer. Future commands will affect this buffer specifically.
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);

GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuf.capacity() * 4,vertexBuf, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

//Main VBO Code from drawSprite method:

```
    vertices[0]=xPlotLeft;
    vertices[1]=yPlotTop;
    vertices[2]=0;
    vertices[3]=0;
    vertices[4]=0;

    vertices[5]=xPlotRight;
    vertices[6]=yPlotTop;
    vertices[7]=0;
    vertices[8]=1;
    vertices[9]=0;

    vertices[10]=xPlotLeft;
    vertices[11]=yPlotBottom;
    vertices[12]=0;
    vertices[13]=0;
    vertices[14]=1;

    vertices[15]=xPlotRight;
    vertices[16]=yPlotBottom;
    vertices[17]=0;
    vertices[18]=1;
    vertices[19]=1;


    //Reset Byte Buffer position

    vertexBuf.rewind();
    vertexBuf.put(vertices).position(0);

// Transfer data from client memory

    GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertexBuf.capacity() * 4,vertexBuf);

    //Bind the texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);      
    //Use program
    GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);
    //Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix2, 0, mvpMatrix, 0,  mRotationMatrix, 0);
    //get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");
    //Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix2, 0);
    //Specify attributes for vertex (X,Y,Z)
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 0);
    //Enable attribute for position
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);
    //Specify attributes for vertex S & T
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * 4, 3 * 4);
    //Enable attribute for texture
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoords);
    //Enable Alpha blending and set blending function
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND); 
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //Draw
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    //Disable Alpha blending
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

}
```

Comment: The whole point (or one of the points) of VBOs is, that you put your data into it only once and not every frame (which wouldn't be much different from the non-VBO code at all). You can use VBOs dynamically, but in your case it seems you're just drawing the same sprite all the time. If not and you really need to upload the coordinates each frame, then at least use `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` (or even `GL_STREAM_DRAW`) as usage flag instead of `GL_STATIC_DRAW` (and take a look into [the usual streaming improvements](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming)).

Comment: And of course VBOs do in absolutely no way *guarantee* a measurable performance difference at all. It depends entirely on your particular application and implementation if there is a performance gain at all (there shouldn't be a degrade, though, if used properly).

Comment: And of course make sure you actually use the buffer for drawing (by doing a proper `glBindBuffer` and using `NULL` instead of `vertexBuf` in `glVertexAttribPointer`), otherwise you'll be just drawing from the client arrays as before (that's why it's a good idea to show your actual code instead of the non-VBO code and just saying *"yeah, the VBO code is similar, just with VBOs"*).

Comment: Thanks @ChristianRau for your comments.  I have edited my question to show my full VBO code as requested. So are VBO's generally not advised for applications where the sprites need to move? (this is a 2D game, therefore, for the most part, about 60% of my sprites need move every frame, therefore I am altering the coordinates each frame).  I.E, do you get more benefit from VBO's when they are applied to 'static' sprites? Does my VBO code look OK?  I am using '0' in the line you mentioned as opposed to Null - would that make a difference?  Thanks for any further help you could offer.

Comment: VBOs are *always* advised. Yet *one* of their strengths is that they can store vertex data on the GPU to not have to upload it everytime, a strength that cannot be played out with dynamic VBOs. Yet they still are highly recommended (and mandatory in modern OpenGL), since they allow the driver to manage the memory in the best way it sees fit. But for this to be succesful you have to give it as much hints as possible, and thus should declare your VBO as dynamic and not static and should also look into the streaming optimization linked in my comment.

Comment: But apart from those mentioned optimizations, the code looks reasonable, but don't forget the `glBindBuffer` in the draw method before using the VBO. It may still be bound from your initialization code, but it is bad practice to rely on any previous bindings from other unknown parts of the application.

Comment: Thanks v. much for the comments again @ChristianRau, I'll have a look at the link you provided :-)